# Why doesn't this test finish when manually waiting for the async event?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, vert.x

Why doesn't the test `endlessTest` finish?

```
private Vertx vertx;

@Before
public void setUp(TestContext context) throws IOException {
    vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    vertx.deployVerticle(MainVerticle.class.getName(), context.asyncAssertSuccess());
}

@After
public void tearDown(TestContext context) {
    vertx.close(context.asyncAssertSuccess());
}

@Test
public void endlessTest(TestContext context) throws InterruptedException {
    final boolean[] done = {false};
    vertx.createHttpClient().getNow(8080, "localhost", "/ping", response -> {
        context.assertTrue(false);
        done[0] = true;
    });
    while (!done[0]) {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
}
```

It does spit `SEVERE: java.lang.AssertionError: Expected true` to the console, but it keeps running until I manually kill it. Why doesn't the exception propagate?

If I use [Async](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/unit/Async.html) with `complete()` to wait instead, it works as expected:

```
@Test
public void endlessTest(TestContext context) {
    Async async = context.async();
    vertx.createHttpClient().getNow(8080, "localhost", "/ping", response -> {
        context.assertTrue(false);
        async.complete();
    });
}
```

The test fails with `java.lang.AssertionError: Expected true`.

Answer (score 0):

You're running on the event loop and your `Thread.sleep()` call is blocking it, therefore it can not process any further events on it, such as receiving the response to your http call.

Creating an `Asnyc` and completing it in the response is absolutely the right way to do it.